# how i can insert data in mysql and retrieve simulteneously in php on the click of one button?

Tags: php, mysql, html

actually i want to send a comment to the each image and it should display just after clicking the button . I am able to do insert and retrieve the comment but it require refresh the page and i don't want to refresh....just like orkut.plz help me i m new in php...

thans to all............

insertimg.php

```
//________________________________________FOR INSERT COMMENT_____________________________________________________
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) 
{
$sql = "INSERT INTO comment(imid, comm) values ('".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST['imgId']))."', '".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST['Comment']))."')";
//$sql = "INSERT INTO comment (com) VALUES ($_POST['Comment'])";
//$sql="UPDATE upload SET comm='$_REQUEST['Comment']'WHERE id='$_REQUEST['imgId']'";
if($result = mysql_query($sql ,$conn)) 
  {

     echo "submited:";

   }
else 
   {
    echo "<h1>problem </h1> ".mysql_error();
   }

}
```

For display comment..

```
$page=$_GET["page"];
$sql = "select comm from comment where imid = '".$page."'";

$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo"Comments:";
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{

 //echo $row['comm'];
 echo "<textarea name=\"Comment\" style=\"background-color:#81F7BE;\">"; echo $row['comm']; echo "</textarea>";
 //echo "<font>";
 echo "<br>";
 echo "<br>";
}   
mysql_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: Look up Ajax, this is the tech you need to use. It will allow the browser via javascript to need information to your scripts without loading a whole page.

Comment: For god's sake do not create queries joining strings. Use prepared statements. Look up MySQLi or PDO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it with AJAX.
You can use something like jQuery Ajax library.

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "inserting.php",
   data: "imid=1&comm=Hi",
   success: function(msg){
     alert( "Ajax Response: " + msg );
   }
 });
```

Comment: thank you for response but i have got a answer there is no need to use ajax just refresh the database after inserting the data by this query:- $q ="select * from table name";